# How does the database represent One-to-One relationship?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using a simple One-to-One relationship in entity framework core 2.0.

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Avatar)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Profile>(p => p.AvatarId);
```

Where every profile has only one avatar.

Looking in database managing apps does not show me (or at least I did not find) any differences between One-to-One and One-to-Many relationships. So what I mean I could not find any special constrains for One-to-One different that One-to-Many.

How does the database know which kind of relationships I defined? If it does not know, why would I then define the type of relationship I am using?

Comment: If you really mean a one-to-one relationship, then why isn't your class a composition of the other class?

Comment: The difference is the *unique* constraint/index on FK column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't see any foreign keys or primary keys in your database then it doesn't know. Or more specifically: it you will be allowed to save data which violates the relationship.

*Integrity* of relationships are enforced in databases with *Foreign Keys* but this certainly does not stop you submitting SQL which joins tables incorrectly.

Here's a link to defining foreign keys that ensures that a one to one relationship is guaranteed based on the data in tables. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56738/one-to-one-one-to-many-table-relationships-in-sql-server/ .